# Is there a difference between text described as a cipher or ciphertext?

Tags: terminology

I've noticed both "cipher" and "ciphertext" being used to describe text encrypted with a cipher.

Here are some definitions from Merriam Webster:

- [**cipher**: a message in code](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cipher)
- [**ciphertext**: the enciphered form of a text or of its elements](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ciphertext)

These appear to be roughly synonymous in this context (though I'm aware "cipher" also have other definitions). Are they interchangeable in this usage, or is there a difference in these two definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cipher" almost always refers to the *method* of encrypting data, rather than the encrypted message itself. The main exception is when the format of the message is itself mysterious; you might refer to such a message as "a cipher" in the sense that you will need to figure it out. You would probably not do this in an information security context, where the proper term for encrypted data is "ciphertext"; in such a context, the use of "cipher" to mean "incomprehensible data" would be confusing.

It's worth noting that several of the definitions Merriam-Webster gives there are outright archaic; I've never seen #1, #3, or #4 in modern or even recent historical context, and #2b is, as noted above, very uncommon and usually more narrowly used than MW describes.

In modern usage, particularly in the context of computers and especially in information security, "cipher" as a noun refers to a process for enciphering (encrypting) and is synonymous with "encryption scheme" or "encryption algorithm". For example, DES and AES are both known as "block ciphers" (encryption algorithms that operate on blocks of data), while Salsa20 is a "stream cipher" (an encryption algorithm that operates on a sequential stream of data, with arbitrary size) and RSA is an "asymmetric cipher" (an encryption algorithm which uses one key for encryption and a different one for decryption).

As a verb, "cipher" - more commonly "encipher" - usually means "encrypt" (or sometimes simply "obfucscate") and "decipher" is to "decrypt" or sometimes simply to make understandable. For example, one might refer to "deciphering" a block of undocumented code to figure out what it does. One might also try to "decipher" something like a file format or network capture that is inscrutable or seeming meaningless.

It is in this sense - "something that needs to be deciphered" - that you might use "cipher" as a noun (referring to the incomprehensible data) without meaning "encryption algorithm". It is of course possible that the data is inscrutable *because* it is encrypted, but it also might just be compressed, or oddly packed, or encoded in an obscure format, or simply non-intuitive in its meaning and structure. You still probably wouldn't pick that usage in an *application security* context though; you might say "it might be [a] ciphertext". If you said "it's a cipher" in what was understood to be a security context, my first thought would be that it's binary code for an encryption algorithm, or a diagram for a cryptographic device, or something similar.

"Ciphertext" simply means text which is encrypted; I've never seen any other meaning from anybody who appeared to know what they were talking about. As such, it's inherently an information security concept. In no context where I know the word "ciphertext" to apply would I use "cipher" in its place.

Comment: So by the end of your post are you saying **cipher** would be a valid synonym of **ciphertext** if I'm in an information security context and using the same definition?

Comment: ... no, not if you want anybody to understand you. In the context of modern infosec, "cipher" really has only one meaning as a noun. (It's not used much as a verb either, without either "en" or "de" as a prefix on it.)

Comment: If somebody were to describe text as "a cipher" I might figure out that they mean "something that probably has meaning but I can't understand it", but (as an infosec person), my first thought would be "that claim contains a type error, unless they mean it's an algorithm in some form of encoding".

Comment: I believe I was looking for the term "cryptogram", as I had ciphertext that I was decrypting as part of a game.

Comment: Ah, that's a relatively obscure word in modern usage but has a very specific meaning: a message which is encrypted. This is distinct from "ciphertext" in that ciphertext refers to _any_ amount of encrypted data, which may be only a snippet of a message, multiple messages at once, or something that isn't really a "message" at all such as data that is encrypted at rest, intended only to be read by its author. In some cases a cryptogram might not be a _complete_ message, but it would be weird to use it for data that is meaningless to the recipient (even after decryption) by itself.